# Everytime I run my code it says that y is not defined

Tags: python

Everytime I run my code it says that y is not defined.  Why?

```py
def main():
     x=str(input("enter first number : "))
     ab=(input("enter operator : "))
     z=str(input("enter second number : "))

if (ab) ==("+"):
     print(float(x)+float(z))
elif (ab) ==("-"):
     print(float(x)-float(z))
elif (ab) ==("/"):
     print(float(x/float(z))
if (ab) ==("*"):
           print(float(x*float(z))
```

Comment: Not a Pi specific question.  There is no y in the code. The code does not compile.

Comment: It's not going to do you any favours if you post syntactically incorrect python that doesn't even demonstrate the problem you're claiming exists. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You missed a couple of ")"

```
def main():
 x=str(input("enter first number : "))
 ab=(input("enter operator : "))
 z=str(input("enter second number : "))

 if (ab) ==("+"):
      print(float(x)+float(z))
 elif (ab) ==("-"):
      print(float(x)-float(z))
 elif (ab) ==("/"):
      print(float(x/float(z)))  

 if (ab) ==("*"):
      print(float(x)*float(z))
```

Comment: To the contrary it has too many parentheses.

Comment: Ah I saw print () and thought python3?